# sorting div elements by inner div element content using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I was trying to make a little script with javascript for sorting div element by their inner div data, for making "Sort by Name" & "Sort By Popularity"...

The problem is, I almost made it even it is all ok in 'Mozila Firefox'. But not working on 'google chrome' and 'IE'.

Please see the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/s8SgJ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//sorting alphebatically start  
function sortByNameAsc(a,b){
    return $(a).find('.captioncss').text() > $(b).find('.captioncss').text();
}

function reorderEl(el){
    var container = $('#NewsSiteList');
    container.html('');
    el.each(function(){
        $(this).appendTo(container);
    });
}
$('.nameAsc').click(function(){
    reorderEl($('.totalcontainercss').sort(sortByNameAsc));
});
//sorting alphebatically END
$('.totalcontainercss').sort(sortByNameAsc).appendTo($('#NewsSiteList')); //sorting alphebatically onLoad

//sorting by popularity start
function sortByPopularityAsc(a,b){
    return $(a).find('.ShortByRank').text() - $(b).find('.ShortByRank').text();
}

function reorderEl(el){
    var container = $('#NewsSiteList');
    container.html('');
    el.each(function(){
        $(this).appendTo(container);
    });
}
$('.PopularAsc').click(function(){
    reorderEl($('.totalcontainercss').sort(sortByPopularityAsc));
}); 
//sorting by popularity END
});
```

Please give me a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, though that's a terribly expensive way to sort. Also, why do you have two identical functions named `reorderEl()` ?

Comment: @CrazyTrain, when you said "expensive", do you mean performance or labour to write the code?

Comment: @BillyChan: Performance... or more specifically computational overhead. DOM selection isn't cheap, nor is creating jQuery objects and calling its methods. It would be better for OP to create an Array of objects that hold the element to be sorted, and the value being compared, then extract the elements from the objects and append them.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, thank you for the detailed explain, learnt. Also a var of array sounds good idea when outputting together with the template. Shuvojit Das, I verified the code in my Chromium, the buttons work, but the dropdown not.

Comment: Can anyone help me out to work this http://jsfiddle.net/s8SgJ/ in all browser. by the way it is working perfect in Firefox.